# Why my C code output garbage value each time i enter 10 for rating input?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Food{
    char* item;
    int rating;
    char reason[30];
    char histogram[11];
};

void removeNewline(char* x){
    char temp[30];
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(x)-1; i++){
        temp[i] = x[i];
    }
    temp[strlen(x)-1] = '\0';
    
    strcpy(x, temp);
}

int main()
{
    struct Food x[10];

    x[0].item = "Burger";
    x[1].item = "Broast";
    x[2].item = "Rice";
    x[3].item = "Roll";
    x[4].item = "Handi";
    x[5].item = "Platter";
    x[6].item = "Kebabs";
    x[7].item = "Sandwich";
    x[8].item = "Shake";
    x[9].item = "Kheer";

    char sum[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        printf("\nEnter score for %s (1 - 10) : ", x[i].item);
        scanf("%d", &x[i].rating);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Enter reason for liking or disliking : ");
        fgets(x[i].reason, 30, stdin);
        removeNewline(x[i].reason);

        strcpy(sum, "*");
        for(int j = 1; j < x[i].rating; j++){
            strcat(sum, "*");
        }
        strcpy(x[i].histogram, sum);
    }

    printf("\n%-13s%-11s%-35s%s\n", "Item", "Rating", "Reason", "Histogram");
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        printf("%-13s%-11d%-35s%s\n", x[i].item, x[i].rating, x[i].reason, x[i].histogram);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Output with garbage value whenever i enter value of 10 for rating input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyPII.jpg)

Why my output will display a garbage value each time i enter 10 for rating ?
Any C expert can help ?
Any C expert can help ?
Any C expert can help ?
Any C expert can help ?
Any C expert can help ?
Any C expert can help ?
Any C expert can help ?
Any C expert can help ?

Comment: You're not checking the return value from `scanf()` - you have no idea what it read, or even if it actually read something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a faster way to remove newlines.

```
name[strlen(name) - 1 = '\0';
```

Where name is the array of chars.

And where you ask the user to enter something 1-10, you might want to subtract from it, to deal with the array start at zero thing.

Hope this fixes your problem!